# Point-wise convergence of function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I have been trying out some questions on sequence of functions.In one of those questions,I am supposed to find the point-wise limit of the following sequence of functions defined on [$0,1$] as
$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
n^2x,  \text{if 0$\le$$x$$\le$$\frac{1}{n}$}\\
-n^2x+2n,  \text{if $\frac{1}{n}$$\le$$x$$\le$$\frac{2}{n}$}\\
0, \text{if $\frac{2}{n}$$\le$$x$$\le$1}
\end{cases}$$
Given this,I am unable to find the limit of f$_n$(x) as n tends to infinity.

Help please!

Comment: Given $x\in[0,1]$, what's the limit of the sequence $(f_n(x))_n$ as $n\to\infty$? Once you answer this question, you should be able to find the pointwise limiting function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it converges to zero everywhere.

Proof:
For $x = 0$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$.  For any other $x$, take $n \ge \frac2x$, for which $f_n(x) = 0$ because $\frac2n \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much